# How to get the content of child->child->child->child in XML file using Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.056.001.01" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <FIToFIPmtCxlReq>
            <Assgnmt>
                <Id>TEST-ISO-81</Id>
                <Assgnr>
                    <Agt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BIC>CCCCGB2L</BIC>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </Agt>
                </Assgnr>
                <Assgne>
                    <Agt>
                        <FinInstnId>
                            <BIC>MMMMGB2L</BIC>
                        </FinInstnId>
                    </Agt>
                </Assgne>
                <CreDtTm>2009-03-24T11:22:59</CreDtTm>
            </Assgnmt>
            <TxInf>
                <CxlId>103012345</CxlId>
                <Case>
                    <Id>ISO_TEST_CASE</Id>
                    <Cretr>
                            <Agt>
                                <FinInstnId>
                                    <BIC>MMMMGB2L</BIC>
                                </FinInstnId>
                            </Agt>
                    </Cretr>
                </Case>
            </TxInf>
     </Undrlyg>
    </FIToFIPmtCxlReq>
</Document>
```

Here I want to get the content of "TxInf" like all its child and child of child and the data.

What I have tried is :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree import ElementTree
tree = ET.parse('R3-CAMT.056.001.07-ISO-V.XML')
root = tree.getroot()
for element in root.iter():
    if element.tag == "{urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.056.001.01}TxInf":
        tree._setroot(element.tag)
        print(root.tag)
        print(root.attrib)
```

Please suggest if I can change the root with _setroot or any other possible method

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: Get the whole content between <TxInf></TxInf>.
May be to print it as new xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along these lines on your code to see if it works:

```
for r in root.findall(".//*"):
    if 'TxInf' in r.tag:
        print(ET.tostring(r))
```

By the way, it may be easier to do it with lxml, if you can use it.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked for me.
Moving forward, I would love to know how to use lxml.
Will do some research. Thanks again.